# De-Duping an Email Correctly

Tags: dataextensions, send-email

I'm about to send an email to two data extensions and I'm a bit unsure of myself when it comes to de-duplicating emails. I really don't want to accidentally send people two emails when I send this.

Each extension has a "key" field that has differently formatted data and each has an email field, set to a field-type of "email address".

When two data extensions are selected and the de-duplicate box is ticked, which fields matter in this? Does it only compare the fields set as the "email address"?

Edit: Subscriber Keys are enabled, the de-duplicate box specifies "De-duplicate by email address"

Answer (score 0):

You can de-dupe with a Query Activity if you'd prefer doing it explicitly with SQL.  That's normally what I do.

Both Data Extensions have the sendable field set to the email address column for the Send Definition de-dupe option to work properly.